# Why is string indexing in Python 3.6 10x slower than NumPy indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why is string indexing in Python 3 10x slower than the same operation with NumPy indexing?

Code to demonstrate (using IPython magic for timing):

```py
import numpy as np

vocab = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,-'
vocab_np = np.array(list(vocab))

ind = np.random.randint(0, len(vocab), size=10000)

%timeit s = ''.join(vocab[i] for i in ind)
# 2.86 ms ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit s = ''.join(vocab_np[ind].tolist())
# 284 µs ± 943 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

(Note that only a single CPU core is active in both cases.)

Comment: They're doing very different things: one is doing a multi-index, very quickly, in C code.  The other is running a list comphrension, in Python.  Numpy is highly optimized for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Max, I was under the impression that list comprehension in Python is heavily optimized. Sure, maybe not to optimized C levels, but 10x slower? It doesn't seem right to me. I'm wondering if there is more to it.

Comment: Not really. Try timing too using a regular for loop @rd11

Comment: Have a look at the number of function calls in each version. Even with list comprehension, `vocab.__getitem__(...)` is called for each element separately; that is `len(vocab)` calls. The numpy version has only two function calls.

Comment: Can you clarify why you feel this is surprising? This is not "the same operation" at all. You call getitem on the string 10000 times in a repeatedly suspended coroutine (aka generator), but on the array only once followed by an array-to-array transformation. Frankly, a factor of 10 seems surprisingly *fast* for indexing ``str`` so often.

Comment: List comprehension is just a bit faster than a regular for loop.  The iteration set up is streamlined, but the action/body is still Python code.  It does not `compile` anything.

Comment: It seems that most time is eaten up by the inefficient generator expression *and numpy iterator*. Using ``str`` indexing with only lists, e.g. ``''.join([vocab[i] for i in ind.tolist()])``, is only 3 times slower than pure numpy. About 10% can be removed by precomputing ``ind.tolist()`` or directly drawing the random numbers into a python list.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go by impressions.  Test!

Focusing on the string operation:

```
In [46]: vocab = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,-'                                             
In [47]: ind = np.random.randint(0, len(vocab), size=10000) 
    ...:                                                                                     
In [48]: s = ''.join(vocab[i] for i in ind)                                                  
In [49]: len(s)                                                                              
Out[49]: 10000
```

Your test case:

```
In [50]: timeit s = ''.join(vocab[i] for i in ind)                                           
1.9 ms ± 2.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

iteration on a list is faster than iteration on an array:

```
In [51]: timeit s = ''.join(vocab[i] for i in ind.tolist())                                  
1.06 ms ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [52]: %%timeit ind1=ind.tolist() 
    ...: s = ''.join(vocab[i] for i in ind1) 
    ...:                                                                      
906 µs ± 511 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The same for loop is just a bit slower:

```
In [53]: %%timeit ind1=ind.tolist() 
    ...: alist = [] 
    ...: for i in ind1: 
    ...:     alist.append(vocab[i]) 
    ...: ''.join(alist) 
    .                                                                     
1.09 ms ± 372 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

List comprehension can produce cleaner, more readable code, but it is **not** a major speed tool.  In this case the `vocab[i]` is still performed each time.  There's no compilation.

===

Using a list comprehension rather than a generator expression improves the time:

```
In [54]: %%timeit ind1=ind.tolist() 
    ...: s = ''.join([vocab[i] for i in ind1])  
    ...:                                                                                     
641 µs ± 58.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`generators` are good if they feed more generators in a series, but by themselves don't do much.